# web scraping from https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/61/35

Tags: web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

Is it possible for me to scrape the data from the pop up appears after clicking the link.the website is https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/61/35

Comment: So, three questions in a row about scraping. This one shows no research. The second one also showed no research (there are a plethora of Q&As on SO about iterating over pages). This is a really bad way to learn web scraping. I get that this is likely a job task that needs to be done, but I suggest taking time to actually learn about web scraping. Any decent organization will allow for time for said personal growth and development _unless_ one claimed expertise that one didn't have.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible, it's just a table with pagination.

But you'd better check the legal part before scraping a website, moreover on a governmental one.

Comment: can u help me how the data I want is in the pop

Comment: You can do it multiple way.As Hanania said: call the API.
 Or use the pagination in the URL and get the table elements.
 Otherwise, with simple scraping, you can just do it in the browser with the console and the local storage but i's not the cleanest way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to follow exactly what browser does. See network behaviour from your browser.

First, you have to send request to https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf in order to get token like this :{"csrf_token":"0d1c59184c7df788dc4b8759f6da40c6"}

After, send another POST request to https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info. As parameters you have to mention **csrf_test_name which** which is equals to csrf_token and **id** which is found from onclick attribute of each link.

You will get JSON as response and just to parse it as you need.